# How to simulate $E[X | \mathcal F_t] $ when there is no Markovianity?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, simulation

Let $(\mathcal F_t)$ be a filtration and $X$ a random variable such that $E[X | \mathcal F_t] \neq X$ and $E[X | \mathcal F_t] \neq E[X]$ for all $t\in [a,b]$. We consider the conditional expectation

$$E[X | \mathcal F_t] $$

How do we simulate paths of the above process when there is no $Y_t$ such that $E[X | \mathcal F_t]=E[X | Y_t]$ ?

Comment: Pretty sure this is going to depend on the specific situation, but my guess would be some sort of least-squares method since $E[X|\mathcal F_t]$ is the $L^2$ projection of $X$ onto $\mathcal F_t$.  You would probably need to add some more details to get a good answer, though.

Comment: For example: Let $(X_t)$ be a fractional Brownian motion. Take $X=X_T$ and $\mathcal F_t$ the filtration generated by $(X_t)$. We consider $t\in (0,T)$.